# How-to do Google search input form transaction position: from center to top

Tags: css, search-engine, html, google-search

I am asking this question after spending more than 10 days, looking for information in books, youtube tutorial for php , mysql, javascript , jquery, and not able to get an answer or some feedback how to do it.

I am doing the search engine in my website and I would like to create the same effect as Google... once you type or input something in the search box the whole page will change from having the search form in the center of the page TO  place it on the header of the page. HOW TO DO THAT???

Answer (score 0):

Your search box is a form. Its going to pass that form data to a script, process it and then output the search results on a new page. You simple apply a different style template to the results page.

If this is an overly simplistic answer for your situation please give more specific information on the search script you are using and whether your website is hardcoded or generated via a CMS solution.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your reply. It is not simple as that. If you open the page of google.com and start typing in the input search box...you will see , right away , it will change the page and place input form in the header. That is the effect that I am trying to achieve. T